# ubuntu 20.04 - ChrootDirectory in sshd_config wont work with tokens %h or %u

Tags: ubuntu, ssh, sftp, chroot

I am trying to lock users into their home directory using a dedicated group in the sshd_config. The section of my group looks as follows

```
Match Group sftponly
ChrootDirectory %h
X11Forwarding no
AllowTcpForwarding no
ForceCommand internal-sftp
```

Using %h or even /home/%u wont work when I try to connect with any user. I checked all permissions on their home directories and everything looks ok.

Interestingly, when I provide ChrootDirectory with a static path, everything works fine.

E.g the following config lets users connect (but in the wrong directory)

```
Match Group sftponly
ChrootDirectory /home/
X11Forwarding no
AllowTcpForwarding no
ForceCommand internal-sftp
```

man sshd_config says that I am using the %h token correctly:

> ChrootDirectory accepts the tokens %%, %h, %U, and %u.

Appreciate any hint since I spent hour on it already

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As answered here [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/134425/how-can-i-chroot-sftp-only-ssh-users-into-their-homes) leading to [here](http://lists.mindrot.org/pipermail/openssh-unix-dev/2009-May/027651.html) the `ChrootDirectory` has to be owned by `root` and can't be any group-write access.

As the home dirs of the specific user is by default owned by that user, your config is not working.

So either `chown` the home directory to `root` and create a folder in it where the user has the right to read/write or use a different `ChrootDirectory`.

Comment: thank you! I didnt stumble across those two pages while searching for a solution. It works fine now